# Using RegEx to find files

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to import a corpus that only takes `txt` files from a folder if the text files are from 2009. The file names are all formatted like this:

```
Mr. ABERCROMBIE.2009-01-14.2014sep17_at_223226.txt
```

I need that first date separated by hyphens to be 2009. I tried to write the regular expression (below) but am really struggling to figure out RegEx and the thing below doesn't work.

```
corpus_root = '/Users/jt/Documents/CRspeeches'
speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '\w.2009-[0-9]-[0-9].*\.txt')
```

Comment: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: `2009-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}` you need to handle the case where it is a 2 digit day/month

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
\.2009-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\..*\.txt$
```

You need to escape the `.`, or it will match any character, and `[0-9]` will match only one digit, hence the `{2}`.

Comment: Maybe is the "Mr." part of the file name?

Comment: This worked: ^\w*\.\s.*2009-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\..*\.txt

Comment: That's weird, the regex in the answer should have yielded a match, but if you need the pattern to match the full string, then you could add `^.*?` at the start of the pattern.